# Condition for login time inside an existing application 

Tags: java

I am working on an existing application, where this below condition is present inside the code, which handles user login.

```
if ((PresentTime - LoginTime) <= browservalidationinsecs) 
{

// Means this is positive and proceed further processing .

}
```

Here the `PresentTime` is the time that is the present time inside the  Server.

The `LoginTime` is the time at which the user has launched the application through the browser.

The `browservalidationinsecs` is hardcoded to 45 Seconds inside the application.

I am unable to understand why this condition is kept .

Could anybody please have any idea ??

Comment: LoginTime is being updated on each user request or both times are not in seconds(but i.e. date) and their substraction results is always less than 45

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This condition might be given for `Time out error`  which is of 45 seconds.

Suppose a user launches an application and does not login for the next 45 seconds,
then after that when he will enter his credentials instead of successful login ,
it will redirect him to the login page again.

This type of code you will find mostly in banking and finance applications where security is the utmost priority.

Comment: what does this mean ?? then after that when he will enter his credentials instead of successful login

Comment: Suppose i launches an application, which means login page has opened. Now you are sitting idle for next 5 mins. And then you are entering your credentials . So during this conditon, it will give time out error. This code means that you have to enter your credentials in the next 45 seconds as you launch your application.